# jQuery "one" method with if else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to implement jQuery's ".one" method with if and else condition. I need to execute this click function only once, whether condition gets true or false.

Please check the below code to simplify my question.

```js
$("span").one("click", function () {
 var ind = $("span").index($(this));
  
 if (ind == 0) {
   alert ("clicked 1st element");
  }
  
  else {
    alert ("clicked 2nd element");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1st click element</span><br>
<span>2nd click element</span>
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? You do not like how it is bound once to each element?

Comment: @epascarello - Currently click event is executing twice if condition gets false first time. I'm needed to execute only once without worrying conditions.

Comment: I thing you want fire event once for two span, not once per span. Do you want it?

Comment: @PunithMithra - You are absolute correct, I'm expecting to execute the statement only once. Currently we can able to click two time even we are using "one" method. That click event should unbind once execute the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have two span tags. So you attached the event **one** for both.

The line:

```
$("span").one("click", function () {
```

is "equivalent" to the following two lines:

```
$("span:eq(0)").one("click", function () {
$("span:eq(1)").one("click", function () {
```

And this is the reason because you receive two events.

If you want to stop the second event and get only the first one you may consider to remove the event handler:

```js
$("span").one("click", function () {
  
  // remove the event for the second span...
  $("span").off("click");
  
  
  var ind = $("span").index($(this));

  if (ind == 0) {
    alert ("clicked 1st element");
  }

  else {
    alert ("clicked 2nd element");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span>1st click element</span><br>
<span>2nd click element</span>
```

Comment: this is what i needed... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("span").one("click", function () {
 var ind = $("span").index($(this)); 
  
  var getRes = (ind == 0) ? alert ("clicked 1st element") : alert ("clicked 2nd element");
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1st click element</span><br>
<span>2nd click element</span>
```